# Getting Session ID for current login

Tags: java, http, session

I am trying to log in to a site and extract HTML data for some of the pages of that site.
The problem is, each link/page of the site contains the session id for the current login.
For example: If I right-click the any link and OPEN IN NEW TAB, the url looks like:

http://02.iswhm.jp/admin/adm_user_search.php?sex=0&**PHPSESSID=xsd6flqcccj24j5evv8ussp76mr1**

From JAVA, if I do not specify the session id, I cannot get html data. For example:

```
String url = "http://02.iswhm.jp/admin/adm_user_search_result.php";
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginstatus[5]", "90"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginstatus[6]", "99"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PHPSESSID", "xsd6flqcccj24j5evv8ussp76mr1"));
```

....
....

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxx", "xxxxx"));

HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(uri);
httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"SJIS"));
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
temp+=line+"\n";
}
```

The above code does not work if I dont specify the PHPSESSID.

How can I get the session ID using JAVA's HTTP API ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, this should be the proper way for it, but you can always get the `cookie` with name `PHPSESSID`, and the value would have the ID. This is a kinda work-around.

Give it a try :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you can use HttpServletRequest interface in which you can use getSession().getId(); you will get the session id. I may be wrong.

Comment: The web site I am trying to access is developed php. I am not sure if it is possible with Servlet API. Please make me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: you can refer to the following site (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136898/using-a-session-with-php-and-java)